# AngularJS UI Router: add variable to scope of state without specifying it in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to pass the attribute `film.title` to the state template **without having to specify it in the state URL**.

index.html:

`<a ui-sref="showtimes({ filmId: film.uid, filmTitle: film.title })">`

app.js:

```
    .state('showtimes', {
        url: '/showtimes/:filmId',
        controller: function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
            $http.get('api/showtimes/?film_id=' + $stateParams.filmId).success(function(data) {
                $scope.showtimes = data;
            });
        },
        templateUrl: 'static/showtimes.html'
    });
```

showtimes.html:

`<p>{{film}}</p>`

I tried adding `$scope.film = $stateParams.filmTitle;` to the controller. It didn't work. I also tried `$scope.film = $state.params.filmTitle;` without any more luck.

Comment: looks like filmTitle is in response data from $http request, I don't think you can get that from $stateParams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify non-URL parameters with `params` property:

```
.state('showtimes', {
  url: '/showtimes/:filmId',
  params: {
    filmTitle: undefined // or "default Title"
  },
  controller: function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams.filmTitle);
    // ...
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: This works. However, after adding `params: { filmTitle: undefined },`, I cannot reload (or copy/paste) the state URL and keep the state: it loads the default URL instead.

Comment: @ArnaudRenaud, what do you mean by "keep the state"? what is "default URL"?

Comment: the default URL is the one I have configured like this: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/films');`. Keeping the state is being able to refresh the page without losing the page layout.

Comment: Actually, after adding `filmTitle` to `params`, the proper state URL remains after reloading but the layout of the page is back to default.

Comment: When you refresh the page, it loses `filmTitle` obviously - the only seed parameters are those that are defined on the URL (not what you intended, though, for `filmTitle`), so the view would render as if `filmTitle === undefined`. As to default url - then, you must not be matching `/showtimes/:filmId`